# Error installing SAP mobile platform SDK 3.0

Tags: sybase, sup, sap-smp

I am trying to install SAP Mobile Platform SMP 3.0 and i got the following error

[image: error screen]

i searched and found out that the cause could be my 32-bit running windows. is is the reason ? and how can  i solve it using a workaround or something ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone through the Sybase documentation on SMP3.0 SDK?
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01996.0301/doc/html/title.html

There are some restrictions on installing SMP components for 32-bit systems. Check the Product Availability Matrix on 'Mobile' (SAP S-number required) : https://websmp205.sap-ag.de/sap/support/pam

Answer (score 2):

According to official SMP 3.0 installation [link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01998.0300/doc/html/jwo1370391409966.html),

> If User Account Control (UAC) is present in the version of Windows
>   where you are installing, disable it. Restart the system for this
>   change to take effect. Access the Control Panel option that manages
>   User Account Control on your version of Windows. Set the user account
>   to never be notified about changes to your computer. Reenable UAC
>   after completing this installation.

So try disabling the UAC before installation (assuming you are logged in as administrator for this installation)